# Plugin: How to make user manage contributors and their permissions to his projects?

Tags: wordpress, user-management

I'd like to find a plugin to help me build a projects site.

A simple use case is the following:

The user buys a bronze-project, he becomes the owner, and that allows him to invite 2 other users to contribute. One as editor, other as viewer.

All users may buy as many projects as they want and contribute on other projects, but only the owners can add contributors and change permissions.

I have searched a lot for a plugin that would help me do it. The closer I got was with wp-client.

obs: The idea here is quite similar to what we have on Assembla or with gDrive, with a little bit of adaptation.

If someone can shine a light on that, I would really appreciate. I'm quite new to wp.